# How to set a flag on the Iphone screen, So that it can be back on this screen when click?

Tags: iphone

I have a project in iphone which has many `UIViewController`. I want to set a flag or something to get back on that `UIViewController`.

How can I do this?

Comment: i discover i will change a UIviewcontroller? any suggesstion?

Comment: can you explain your viewcontrollers hierarchy ?

Comment: i have rootViewController inherit from TableViewController, which manage for four or three screen, depending to the data read from .plist file. it's dynamic. i want to make a flag a status of screen to be back on that screen  after sending sms. the flow of my app may be like this. rootView.main -> rootView.payment -> rootView.trainticket -> inputcontroller (now it goes to another class) -> sending sms. after sending successfull i want to go back to rootView.payment. any ideal???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find out to be reload data for tableDataSource using like this:

```
    -(void)reloadData:(NSArray *)data andCurrentLevel:(NSInteger) alevel{
    RootViewController *root =[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
//    RootViewController *root = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
    root.tableDataSource = data;
    [root.tableView reloadData];
    root.CurrentLevel = alevel;
}
```

in my button send sms. i have add following lines:

```
 NSArray *data = newDataSource;
    [self reloadData:data andCurrentLevel:newCurrentLevel];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

it can be going back to screen i want. but i have the problem with my navigationbar button

Comment: if you  think that your question solved with your answers than accept your answer..